# .net Listen printer status

Tags: c#, printing, wmi

I need to listen Status changes on a specific printer, but don't want to implement it with a timer, There is a way to listen this changes suscribing to one event?

Actually I'm using

```
loPrinter.PrinterState = (UInt32)printer.Properties["PrinterState"].Value;
```

On a Timer.

Answer (score 0):

You can provided the loPrinter object has set event exposed. There is nothing wrong with using a timer though and you wouldn't have to do it more than once every 2 - 3 seconds.